# jQuery Dialog, simplifying code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jQuery Dialog as follows:-

```
    <a href="#" id="faq-1"><li><span class="black">- I paid for a journey on credit card and at a later date I got further charges. Why?</span></li></a>

    <div id="faq-1a" class="faq-a" title="I paid for a journey on credit card and at a later date I got further charges. Why?">
        <p>When a booking is made via credit card we take the payment for the journey quoted. If for any reason the journey was amendments i.e.  Waiting time or an extra drop off, these charges are separately billed therefore shown as a separate transaction on your statement.</p>
    </div>

    <a href="#" id="faq-2"><li><span class="black">- How do I get a receipt for a journey I made using my credit card?</span></li></a>

    <div id="faq-2a" class="faq-a" title="How do I get a receipt for a journey I made using my credit card?">
        <p>If you are a registered user please use your online booking management via our website <a href="index.php">www.one2onecars.com</a>. you will have access to all your journeys with the option to print out receipts for each journey or as a summary statement. If you are not registered, you can email <a href="mailto:creditcardreceipts@one2onecars.com">creditcardreceipts@one2onecars.com</a> for your receipts.</p>
    </div>
```

JQUERY

```
   $(function() {

        $('.faq-a').dialog({
          modal: true,
          resizable: false,
          draggable: false,
          width: '585',
          autoOpen: false,
          position: [370,455],
        });
    });

});

    $("#faq-1").bind('click', function(){

        $("#faq-1a").dialog('open')

    });

    $("#faq-2").bind('click', function(){

        $("#faq-2a").dialog('open')

    });
```

I would need to do this for 10 different dialogs, so `#faq-x` will range from `#faq-1` to `#faq-10`

I'm sure there would be an easier way to write this so that I wouldn't have to keep repeating:

```
$("#faq-3").bind('click', function(){

    $("#faq-3a").dialog('open')

});
```

For every dialog I create, I just can't figure out how I could do this so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can write the below for loop simply in jquery.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i ++) {
     $("#faq-" + i).bind("click", function() {
         $("#faq-" + i + "a").dialog("open")
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't create Class, instead of unique IDs?

for your #faq-1, #faq-2,........,#faq-10 assign all of them same class e.g, faqClass

```
$(".faqClass").bind('click', function(){
    $("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "a").dialog('open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add your jquery bindings to classes and add additional data-attributes to your anchors :

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/qV578/1/

HTML :

```
<a href="#" data-dialog="one" class="dialog-link">Link</a>
<div id="one" class="dialog">Dialog fired by Link</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.dialog').dialog({
      modal: true,
      resizable: false,
      draggable: false,
      width: '585',
      autoOpen: false,
      position: [370,455]
    });

$('.dialog-link').bind('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target_dialog = $(this).attr('data-dialog');
    $('#'+target_dialog).dialog('open');
});
```